# Looking for very fast fixed length string search algorithm in a fixed length string database

Tags: design-patterns, matching

I would appreciate suggestions for very very fast algorithm that determine if an 8 bytes string is NOT present in a database of strings where each string is also 8 bytes in length.  There are a couple of hundred millions of strings in the database.  There may be clusters of strings in the database. I am thinking of using the Aho Corasick algorithm, but I hopethat there may be faster technique.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't care what algorithm you find, row-scanning hundreds of millions of rows as a solution is typically highly frowned upon.  The type of operation you are performing is intended to be solved by using database indexes, as you can make these determinations near instantly.  Since you said what you are searching on matches (byte count) what is in the database, using indexes should fit in quite nicely.